Polynomial has n real roots
a) Assume that the equation $f(x) = x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \dots +a _n = 0$ has $n$ real roots $x_1,\dots x_n$ (that means $f(x_i) = 0$ and $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ $\forall i$). Prove that:
$$\prod\limits_{i = 1}^{n}(1+ x_i^2) = (1 - a_2 + a_4 - \dots)^2 + (a_1- a_3 + a_5 + \dots)^2.$$
b) Prove that $f(x) = 0$ cannot have $n$ real roots if $(1 - a_2 + a_4 - \dots)^2 + (a_1- a_3 + a_5 + \dots)^2 < 2^n a_n$.
I got stuck and I don't have any idea that can be used to solve this. Can anybody help me?

are you sure it is not $(1+x_i^2)$?

Oh, it's my mistake, thank you.

Hint. Rewrite left part using complex numbers:
$$
\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+x_j^2\right)=
\prod_{j=1}^n\left[\left(1+\textbf i \:x_j\right)\left(1-\textbf i \:x_j\right)\right]
$$
Then try to use Vieta's formulas. General idea is to find the way to use $x_j$ instead of $x_j^2$.
UPD (using @Exodd hint):
Let's define the following function:
$$
g(z):=\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-\frac{x_j}{z}\right)=
\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{z-x_j}{z}=\frac{1}{z^n}\prod_{j=1}^n\left(z-x_j\right)=
\frac{f(z)}{z^n}
$$
Then
$$
\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+x_j^2\right)=
\prod_{j=1}^n\left[\left(1+\textbf i \:x_j\right)\left(1-\textbf i \:x_j\right)\right]=
\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+\textbf i\:x_j\right)\cdot\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-\textbf i\:x_j\right)=
$$
$$
=\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-\frac{x_j}{\textbf i}\right)\cdot\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+\frac{x_j}{\textbf i}\right)=
g(\textbf i)g(-\textbf i)
$$
Now we notice that $g(\bar z)=\overline{g(z)}$, so
$$
g(\textbf i)g(-\textbf i) = |g(\textbf i)|^2=
\left|\frac{f(\textbf i)}{\textbf i^n}\right|^2 = 
\left|f(\textbf i)\right|^2
$$
That's it. Not to deal with some technical stuff (general $n$ case, a lot of indices...) let's show for small $n=4$:
$$
\left|f(\textbf i)\right|^2=
\left|\textbf i^4+a_1\textbf i^3+a_2\textbf i^2+a_3\textbf i+a_4\right|^2=
$$
$$
=\left|1-a_1\:\textbf i-a_2+a_3\:\textbf i+a_4\right|^2=
\left|(1-a_2+a_4)-\textbf i\:(a_1-a_3)\right|^2=
$$
$$
=(1-a_2+a_4)^2+(a_1-a_3)^2
$$

there's no need even forVieta's formulas here

@Exodd if you have other idea or even complete solution, you can share or give a hint

$\prod_{j=1}^n\left[\left(1+\textbf i :x_j\right)\left(1-\textbf i :x_j\right)\right] = f(-\textbf i )f(\textbf i ) = |f(\textbf i )|^2$
